# How to join two frames' rows in H2O?

Tags: java, h2o

I am implementing my own algorithm in H2O's Java source code (under package `h2o-algos`).

How can I join two frames' rows (i.e. vectors) in H2O given H2O Java methods?

For instance, given two Frame A and B

```
Frame A:

| Id       | Name           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123      | John           |
| 456      | Bob            |
Frame B:
| Id       | Name           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 789      | Alice          |
```

I want the resultant Frame C to be:

```
| Id       | Name           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123      | John           |
| 456      | Bob            |
| 789      | Alice          |
```

Is there a way to do this faster then: making new vectors, than create a new frame from the new vectors? I have read the documentation and found that the `Frame::append()` method would create new columns, not joining rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is called "row binding", it is not exposed as an API method. It is, however, available as a Rapids expression (simple scheme-like language). You can follow this example to row-bind 2 H2O Frames: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/test/java/water/rapids/ast/prims/mungers/AstRBindTest.java#L40 In a nutshell, if you have 2 frames with keys A and B you would run water.rapids.Rapids.exec("rbind A B").getFrame()